# Removing a shape in canvas and Socket IO After a User Disconnects

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, html5-canvas

So, I was working on a multiplayer game in SocketIO and Canvas, and I ran into a problem. Whenever a user would disconnect from the game, their character would still be there. I figured that the way to fix this was to remove their drawing or character from the game when they disconnect, but I just couldn't figure out how to do this. Please help! Thankyou!

Heres my code:

server.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var http = require('http');
    var path = require('path');
    var socketIO = require('socket.io');

    //starts the express app
    var app = express();
    var server = http.Server(app);
    var io = socketIO(server);

    //where to run the server
    app.set('port', 5000);
    //Static files such as css, html, and javascript
    app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    // Routing
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    });

    //Starting the Server
    server.listen(5000, function() {
      console.log('server running on port 5000');
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    });

    setInterval(function() {
      io.sockets.emit('message', 'hi');
    }, 1000);

    //player connection
    var players = {};
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('new player', function() {
        players[socket.id] = {
          x: 300,
          y: 300
        }
      });

      socket.on('movement', function(data) {
        var player = players[socket.id] || {};

        if(data.left) {
          player.x -= 5;
        }
        if(data.up) {
          player.y -= 5;
        }
        if(data.right) {
          player.x += 5;
        }
        if(data.down) {
          player.y += 5;
        }
      });

      socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        io.emit('user disconnected', 'user disconnected');
      })
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      io.sockets.emit('state', players);
    }, 1000 / 60);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         canvas {
         width: 800px;
         height: 600px;
         border: 5px solid black;
         }
      </style>
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="gameBoard">
         <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
      <script>
         var socket = io();
         socket.on('message', function(data) {
           console.log(data);
         });


         socket.emit('new player');
         setInterval(function() {
           socket.emit('movement', movement);
         }, 1000/ 60);

         //Actual Canvas Code
         var movement = {
           up: false,
           down: false,
           left: false,
           right: false
         }

         document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
           switch(event.keyCode) {
             case 65:
               movement.left = true;
               break;
             case 87: 
               movement.up = true;
               break;
             case 68:
               movement.right = true;
               break;
             case 83: 
               movement.down = true;
               break;
           }
         });

         document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
           switch(event.keyCode) {
             case 65:
               movement.left = false;
               break;
             case 87:
               movement.up = false;
               break;
             case 68:
               movement.right = false;
               break;
             case 83:
               movement.down = false;
               break;
           }
         });

         var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
         canvas.width = 800;
         canvas.height = 600;
         var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
         socket.on('state', function(players) {
         context.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
         context.fillStyle = 'green';
         for (var id in players) {
         var player = players[id];
         context.beginPath();
         context.arc(player.x, player.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
         context.fill();
         }

         });

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the disconnect event to do find and delete the user:

```
socket.on('disconnect', ()  => {
    let i = players.indexOf(socket.id);
    players.splice(i, 1);
    socket.emit('userDisconnect', socket.id); 
    //you can use socket.id to identify the user in the front end
    //and delete his objects if necessary
});
```

Comment: Is this in the client?

Comment: This is in the back end, in the end of your example code in server.js.

Comment: could you maybe give me an example of what I could do with this code in the front end?

Comment: It is returning me with the error of `TypeError: players.indexof is not a function`.

Comment: it is indexOf, not indexof, capital O.

Comment: Okay, well, this didn't really help that much, I figured it out on my own, but thank you anyway for answering!

Comment: @T.Bragg If you figured out a solution you could add it as an answer. That might help other users.